# Converting the adjectives "new" and "done" to nouns

Tags: word-choice, word-request, adjectives, nouns

In our software, we have the following nomenclature.

- *new* (inactive process)
- *progressing* (ongoing process)
- *failed* (finished process)
- *done* (finished process)

I'd like to rename those states using nouns instead of adjectives.

- *???* (inactive process)
- *progress* (ongoing process)
- *failure* (finished process)
- *???* (finished process)

What'd be a adequate alternative for the question marks? Preferably something not very lengthy so that the code looks nice. It's also possible to consider a different word as long as it reflects the actual state of its process (i.e. *not started yet* and *run and fine*).

My suggestion for *new* doesn't feel right at all: *executability*. It's a bit better in regard to *done*, though: *success*.

Comment: This makes me think of *arrival* and *departure*, though they're not necessarily the best word choices, imho.

Comment: Aehm, you realize that "progressing" and "failed" aren't nouns?

Comment: @Stephie Yes, I do realize that. *Progress* and *failure* are. Have I happen to mistakenly write the other way around? If so, please point out where because I can't find it. The first list is **adjective based** (containing the adjectives *progressing* and *failed*) while the second, that I'm intending to switch, to is **noun based** (containing the nouns *progress* and failure*).

Comment: @DamkerngT. Well, we're creating files and the state might me *no process **yet*** (that's the *new* one) and *no process **any more*** (that's the *done* one). Regrettably, *arrivals* and *departures* are not suitable in my case. Sorry if I haven't provide sufficiently much background information.

Comment: Seems like "initiation" and "success" ought to be decent complements to "progress" and "failure".  You could use "start" instead of "initiation". Or, "commencement".

Comment: @VictorBazarov *Start* is the best candidate for *new* this far. However, I feel that it (as well as *initiation* and *commencement* imply slightly that the process is starting right now or at least about to start any time soon. In my case, the state *new* can take several hours and, in some cases, will be removed without ever reaching the state of execution.

Comment: Also, *failed* is *finished?* And two finishes?

Comment: @MaulikV It's a matter of semantics - a **failed** process isn't running (it's finished) but it's not really **done** (it's not completed).

Comment: @Jojodmo *Complete* isn't a noun, is it? At any rate, post *init* and *success* as a reply instead of a comment and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten *complete* isn't but `completion` is, I still think `success` sounds a little better for code. Your choice, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `init` (short for `initialization`) instead of *new*, which is commonly used in programming, and `success` or `completion` instead of *finished*

> new > `init`
>
> progressing > `progress`
>
> failed > `failure`
>
> done > `success`